# Как осуществить переключение с одного View Controller на другой программно?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Как можно программно переключиться на другой view controller в сторибоарде при первом запуске приложения

Comment: так программно или в сториброде?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko программно, имею ввиду контроллеры в сторибоарде. Nav controllera нет

Comment: тогда либо модально, либо заменять у окна rootViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала задаешь идентификатор своему контроллеру в сториборде, а потом в AppDelegate в методе 
application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    if(...){
    UIStoryboard *controllerStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ИМЯ ТВОЕГО СТОРИБОРДА" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller = [controllerStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР ТВОЕГО КОНТРОЛЛЕРА"];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    }
```

Comment: А как в дальнейшем инициировать этот код?

Comment: ну видишь стоит " if (...) {}" сначала, т.е. допустим у тебя какой-то онбординг (то что ты можешь полистать и ознакомиться с приложением), предположим у тебя там есть кнопка "пропустить" или "начать работу" (ну ты понял), при нажатии на кнопку сохранишь BOOL в NSUserDefaults, а дальше в выше приведенном if-е будешь чекать, есть или нет что-то по такому-то ключу в NSUserDefaults. И если нет - значит еще не смотрел онбординг(в нашем случае), соотвественно показываешь онбординг, а иначе показываешь как-то main контроллер :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот в `AppDelegate` можешь указать:

```
if (...) {  
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

            ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = vc;

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
```